# WSO2 API Manager - Expose Publisher & Store URLs to public

Tags: api, tomcat, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) for creating and managing a developer community. According to my knowledge API manager is driven on WSO2 Carbon Server which again runs on Apache Tomcat.

Up to now I'm able to run WSO2 API manager without any issues. I could open up store and publisher using below urls.

```
https://<MyHostName>:9443/publisher
https://<MyHostName>:9443/store
```

What I want to know is, how can I expose these two URLs to public? I would like something like below as URLs(without ports).

```
https://<MyHostName>/publisher
https://<MyHostName>/store
```

or

```
https://publisher.<MyHostName>
https://store.<MyHostName>
```

*Given that for URLs without https(just http) would be great if possible.*

**In WSO2 API Manager, How can I expose Publisher & Store URLs to public?**

Comment: I feel like it would be much cleaner if you front an nginx and proxy pass the request to the required url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by editing `catalina-server.xml` file located in `<APIM>/repository/conf/tomcat` folder. Change the `port` and `redirectPort` values specified in NIO Connectors.

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="80"
                redirectPort="443" 
                bindOnInit="false"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                acceptorThreadCount="2"
                maxThreads="250"
                minSpareThreads="50"
                disableUploadTimeout="false"
                connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
                maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
                acceptCount="200"
                server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
                compression="on"
                compressionMinSize="2048"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg" 
                URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

    <Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="443"
                bindOnInit="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                acceptorThreadCount="2"
                maxThreads="250"
                minSpareThreads="50"
                disableUploadTimeout="false"
                enableLookups="false"
                connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
                maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
                acceptCount="200"
                server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
                clientAuth="false"
                compression="on"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                compressionMinSize="2048"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
                URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: I end up with browser error Unable to connect(Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at). Do I have to front API Manager with an Apache? If so how?

Comment: Have you changed the redirectPort in http Connector? And does the same problem occur when you try to access through https?

Comment: Yes, I changed the port numbers as given above

Comment: Then the other thing to verify is whether API Manager has started up properly, without any errors. In Unix environments you have to start it as sudo, since it uses port 80 and 443.

Comment: I found a weird solution for this. Just thought of letting you know. API Manager needs Apache server when you change the ports. Apache server should NOT be running as well. Otherwise exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I am getting exception for the HTTP port 80 when trying above configs.. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-80]]. Started as sudo . https console works just bot the http store

Comment: @Techie , by Apache server do you mean tomcat?

Comment: You  literally meant apache-server ;) I turned apache server off and viola