# WSO2 Expose API Store to Consumers?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How would I expose the API Store to a consumer/public/any machine besides mine ? Is this not the purpose of a store?

Putting this URL (that I use) into another persons computer does not yield anything...

```
https://<myIPAddress>:9463/store
```

I have tried following this Q , to no success

[WSO2 API Manager - Expose Publisher & Store URLs to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914851/wso2-api-manager-expose-publisher-store-urls-to-public)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WSO2 API Manager - Expose Publisher & Store URLs to public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914851/wso2-api-manager-expose-publisher-store-urls-to-public)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify the difference of https://<myIPAddress>:9463/store and 
https://publisher/store

(https://publisher/store means https://publisher:80/store)

So the difference is port and the host.

Changing host can be done using DNS entry and to redirect port 80 (default port) can be done as explain in the answer of [WSO2 API Manager - Expose Publisher & Store URLs to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914851/wso2-api-manager-expose-publisher-store-urls-to-public).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with using a wrong port with the https protocol in the address. Following are the ports associated with http and https in APIM.
HTTP - 9763
HTTPS - 9443

**So, you should try either
https://:9443/store or
http://:9763/store**

What you have tried is
https://:9463/store

For above two URLs to work, your ip and port should be accessible by the other machines. If they are in the same network, it won't be an issue. If not, you will have to have public IPs.